# PayPal sandbox recurring payment in one currency failing despite available funds in another currency

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have a PayPal Express Checkout setup to create recurring payment profile using BRL (Brazil Real) as a currency. That works fine in sandbox as long as user has funds in BRL.

However for users without BRL funds recurring profile is created, but transaction is never made. It's just delayed and I get IPN saying that it failed. When I sign in as the user with failed recurring payment I don't get any message that my subscription payment failed, nor I can pay it manually. (note that sandbox users have box credit card added and PayPal funds available just in different currency)

Is there a way to tell PayPal to use funds in any currency that user has available to pay for the subscription?

Comment: I also implented Paypal Express Checkout, but I got error code and message in SetExprexCheckoutResponse when I added not supported curency for saller. Are you call this method? Now, have you probelm with buyer currency?

Comment: @herry it wasn't a problem with PayPal communication. As user1122249 said in his response, there's a setting allowing buyer to convert currency automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i remember, sign into the sandbox merchant account, and change the settings.

My Account -> Profile -> My selling tools -> Block Payments -> Accept Currency and Convert to Currency Radio Button. That should fix the failed message

Comment: I was coming here to suggest the same

Comment: I'm convinced that I've turned that on - and it worked. I'm not sure why it switched back to not doing conversion.